# jinja2 to post dataframe tables on web

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask ,Jinja2 template(html file) to post the panda dataframe tables which are stored in results in ABC.py.
 Table looks like :[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmTq.png)

I am using dictionary to print it but it is not coming in right format

```html
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
          {% if results is not none  %}
            <h2>Compare</h2>
            <br>
            <div id="results">
               <table class="table table-striped" style="max-width: 300px;">
                 <thead>
                   <tr>
                     <th>Specifications</th>
                     <th>part1</th>
                     <th>part2</th>
                   </tr>
                 </thead>
                 {% for key,value in results.iterrows() %}
                    <tr> <option value = {{value[0]}} </option> </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <option value = "{{value[0]}}">{{value[1]}}</option>
                    </tr>
                 #  <option value="{{ value['0']}}">{{value['1'] }}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
                </table>
              </div>
           {% endif %}
       </div>
```

Have to do other things using jinja2 templates but stuck at very ground level.
Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can directly render a table by adding the below to your template file:

```
{{ results.to_html() | safe}}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote and accept it as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Works thank you. Is there any option to format and paginate it?

Comment: @AyenewYihune I used Jquery Datatables to achieve that.